# How to set `meta:redirect` or `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com" />` in Next.js 13 metadata object?

Tags: javascript, next.js, metadata, next.js13

I want to redirect users from one of my pages. I used to do it with redirect metatag. However, I don't find similar options in `metadata` api in Next.js 13 `appRouter`.

Answer (score 0):

redirect metadata does not have any built-in support yet.
[image]

Checkout - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#unsupported-metadata

We can use appropriate HTTP Headers via redirect(), Middleware, Security Headers

```
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
 
async function fetchTeam(id) {
  const res = await fetch('https://...')
  if (!res.ok) return undefined
  return res.json()
}
 
export default async function Profile({ params }) {
  const team = await fetchTeam(params.id)
  if (!team) {
    redirect('/login')
  }
 
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#unsupported-metadata

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMJRO.png

http-equiv is unsupported but they can still be rendered in the layout or page itself.!!

> just add head and meta tag in your layout.js

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: '...',
  description: '...',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta httpEquiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />
      </head>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

This article will help you : https://neunggu.tistory.com/53